# Predicate is not working with NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I want to filter Places where categoryId == value but my predicate is failing.
Here is my code.
categoryList is an array of Objects of class VenueCategory and categoryId is property of Category class.

[image: Place]

```
 class Place: NSManagedObject {

     class func GetPlaces(keys:[String],values:[String],forPlaceTab:Bool?,visitType:VisitType) -> [Place] {

    //1
    let managedContext = CoreDataStack.sharedStack().mainContext

    var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:TABLE_PLACE)

    for (index, key) in keys.enumerate() {
        let value = values[index]

            let predicateFormat =  key != "categoryId" ? "\(key) == \(value)" : "ANY categoryList.categoryId == \(value)"
            let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateFormat)
            predicates.append(resultPredicate)



    }

    if let forPlaceTab = forPlaceTab{

        let predicateFormat = "isPlaceTab == \(forPlaceTab.boolValue)"
        let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: predicateFormat)
        predicates.append(resultPredicate)
    }

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)

    //3
    //var error: NSError?
    do {

        if let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Place]{
            return results
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    return []
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem. issue was categories were not getting added in categoriesList. predicate was Ok.